# Azure Service plans billing

Tags: azure

I am trying to understand the azure service plan and how it effect our project's budget.

To give some background, we have two web applications running under Azure Cloud services in single instance auth.foo.com and api.foo.com. This was a good and convenient way to save some money as you still have to pay for one cloud service. We were doing this using hostheaders to deploy two apps on a same IIS instance.

With new WebApp model I understand we can not do the same thing.

Enter the app service plan. I understand its a grouping mechanism to group your apps so that they can be under one roof. The thing I am not clear about is how its billed? So If I have both apps under a same app service plan does it mean I get billed for two apps or just for one?

Comment: App Service pricing  is clearly explained at azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service (and there's an entire suite of documentation at azure.com as well, explaining how things work). This type of question (billing) is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of an App Service Plan as a mapping from sites to servers. So you can have a large amount of small apps running on a couple of servers, or a small amount of large apps running on the same couple of servers. Provided that your App Service Plan is the same SKU and there are the same amount of instances in each, these will be the same cost.

That's why the billing page: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/plans/ has unlimited for the number of web apps. So to answer your question specifically, you will get billed for one App Service Plan regardless of the number of apps you have in it, since regardless of the number of apps, you'll be using the same amount of servers.